# Suitable GUI framework for Scala?

Tags: java, scala, user-interface

By suitable, I mean:

- mature and used extensively
- rich widget set that renders well
- idiomatic Scala
- Got a WYSIWYG-ish but flexible GUI builder
- standalone API documentation (if a wrapper, it shouldn't make me refer the parent project in another language)

In no particular order.

Which GUI toolkits satisfy which conditions?

Comment: Not looking at Java based frameworks is not helpful. There's Scala Swing, which partially wraps Swing and comes with Scala. There are probably smaller projects trying to build Scala wrappers around stuff like JavaFX 2.0 or SWT. I think other (even) Java frameworks will not satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I don't think a GUI builder for Scala exists. You can cut and paste the Java code generated by NetBeans etc into IntelliJ for automatic translation to Scala, but it's a pain if you subsequently want to change the layout, and you'll just be using Java Swing so it's not idiomatic, but unfortunately there's no alternative currently.

Comment: What am I going to suggest you is what I do nowadays for GUI. Develop your GUI in HTML(5) and JavaScript (AngularJS is nice) and then you can develop a very tiny server in your app to expose some REST-like services for your GUI. You can open the app page (localhost:your-server-port) in the system's default browser or you can embed a browser component in a JFrame. My justification behind this solution is that HTML is the most platform independent and the most rich GUI library on the earth. Even Oracle officially stated that Swing is not going to be maintained very long.

Answer (score 40):

Scala has its own Swing library. This will use the standard Swing library under the hood but it has some nice additions and most notably, because it's made for Scala, it can be used in a much more concise way than the standard Swing library:

```
import swing._

object HelloWorld extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Hello, World!"
    contents = new Button {
      text = "Click Me!"
    }
  }
}
```

See how nice and easy it is to set widget properties?

Except for the nicer syntax and the small additions (like the `SimpleSwingApplication` class), I think the advantages and disadvantages are pretty much the same as with vanilla Swing.

Here's an [Overview of Scala Swing](http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/8).

Comment: Doesn't that look like lots of indentation? Anything to avoid the boomerang effect?

Answer (score 26):

ScalaFX is a mature wrapper around JavaFX 2. It is superficially similar to Scala Swing in some regards, but has some features that make it stand out:

- Couplings to native graphics libraries - This means access to hardware acceleration and other goodies, but requires the JavaFX runtime to be installed on the system. It is included in most major distributions of Java 8. This also means it renders very well on the systems with which it's compatible.
- Property bindings - This is the killer feature for me. Say that I have three elements: `A`, `B`, and `C`. `A` and `B` are resizable, and `C` is supposed to have a height which is the sum of the heights of `A` and `B` at all times. In Swing, this would involve writing a set of custom event listeners to perform this work. ScalaFX bindings lets you express this simply by using the property bind operator: `C.height <== A.height + B.height`. This, among other features, makes for a very Scala-idiomatic feel.
- JavaFX Scene Builder (in beta as of writing) is a WYSIWYG GUI editor (I haven't tried it, though).
- Documentation is its weak point. Being a wrapper, it often refers back to the JavaFX documentation.

Answer (score 18):

I use Java Swing. Here's how it stacks up against your requirements:

- mature and used extensively: yes, a ton.
- rich widget set and renders well: this is debatable. When you consider the ability to easily supplement Java Swing with additional libraries (eg SwingX), it at least does better than Scala Swing in this regard, though probably not as well as some other Java toolkits (though I can't speak to those).
- idiomatic Scala: not as bad as you might think. A few helper functions make it better:

  ```
  implicit class And[A](a: A) {
    def and(f: A => Unit): A = {
      f(a); a
    }
  }
  ```

  So that you can do

  ```
  val button = (new JButton("Press me!")
      and (_ setForeground Color.red)
      and (_ setFont new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 12)))

  val win = (new JFrame("Hello!")
    and (_ add button)
    and (_ pack())
    and (_ setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    and (_ setVisible(true)))
  ```

  Now as for events and state, this is still, in my opinion, a rough edge in *all* gui frameworks -- listeners have their problems, event streams have their problems. I have had general success in augmenting Swing's events with [reactive-core](https://github.com/nafg/reactive/tree/master/reactive-core) and [redo-signals](https://github.com/ellbur/redo-signals) (my own, undocumented) in order to make it easier to organize state.

  You can improve the verbosity of defining listeners with a few more helper functions like

  ```
    def actionListener(f: => Unit) = new ActionListener {
      def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent) { f }
    }
  ```

  and

  ```
    def later(thing: => Unit) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable {
        def run() {
          thing
        }
      })
    }
  ```

  Personally, I wish Scala Swing had taken this route. Writing wrappers for existing Java classes is O(n) programmer time, and doesn't get you anything for the classes that the authors didn't choose to write wrappers for. Creating generic syntactic sugar will take you much farther faster.
- Got a WYSIWYG-ish but flexible GUI builder: I use IntelliJ IDEA forms, to make an abstract class, and then subclass it with a Scala class. The organizational cost is only 1 extra file, and I write no Java code.
- Standalone API documentation: Yes.

Answer (score 8):

Now that some time has passed, it's worth noting that ScalaJS is also an option to consider.

Against your requirements:

- mature and used extensively -- HTML/CSS/JS are, ScalaJS is not (but it's surprisingly good considering). So, you may run into ScalaJS-specific hangups, but the underlying technology is very robust.
- rich widget set that renders well -- Yes.
- idiomatic Scala -- No: you'll end up using a lot of jquery, which will mostly be dynamically typed. [ScalaTags](http://lihaoyi.github.io/scalatags/) does a lot towards making it better though.
- Got a WYSIWYG-ish but flexible GUI builder -- Yes, many.
- standalone API documentation (if a wrapper, it shouldnt make me refer the parent project in another language) -- Yes.

The downside is that it takes your GUI off the JVM and into the browser, so you can't use all those Java libraries.

Comment: If you choose to go in this direction (which you should, scala.js is *awesome*!), there is a really nice tutorial here: http://lihaoyi.github.io/hands-on-scala-js/ . The libraries by lihaoyi are also rock solid - scalatags, autowire, upickle, utest - you should check them out.

Answer (score -25):

I'd say use .Net its mature and used extensively.

But ...

I assume that you require to use Scala. For that I'd stick to Java as it has better tool support like in IDEA or NetBeans. You can of course mix Java and Scala. So your GUI can be done in Java that calls Scala backend. Also take a look at JGoodies they have lot of nice stuff to build UI in Swing. At this moment there is no tool support for Scala GUI applications (and for non GUI it is still behind Java).

Comment: JGoodies Binding is a really good way to functionally describe a UI. Its ValueModel concept is very similar to Lenses. I wish someone would write a scala wrapper or implementation.

Comment: Can you call .Net from Java?

Comment: Okey... but by wich way this is an answer to the question ?